# Pourquoi pas la voix passive?

Tags: passif, style-de-rédaction, voix-passive

J'ai lu cette phrase:

> Les motifs *rendus* par la juge du procès sont des motifs de première instance exemplaires de par leur rigueur

Ceci semble être la voix passive mais sans le verbe auxilliare « être ».

Comment appelle-t-on la phrase « rendus par la juge du procès » ? En anglais, je pense qu'on l'appelle une « participial phrase ».

Et pourquoi pas:

> Les motifs *qui sont rendus* par la juge du procès...

Comment: "La juge du procès" n'est pas une tournure courante. C'est un texte original ou une traduction ?

Comment: @jlliagre C'est au [Canada](https://decisions.scc-csc.ca/scc-csc/scc-csc/fr/item/18881/index.do), ce qui [explique](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17044940). Parfois tu vas aussi trouver _juge des faits_ il me semble, dont l'appréciation est souveraine dans le sens qu'il en faudra beaucoup pour qu'en appel on revise son analyse de la preuve dont celle par témoignage etc.

Comment: @Baie Ah, merci ! Je me disais bien... Au moins, vous ne semblez pas appeler certains juges "justice", ce qui m'avait très intrigué quand j'avais découvert l'appellation *Chief justice* (Cour suprême des États-Unis).

Comment: @jlliagre Pas de [danger](https://www.scc-csc.ca/court-cour/welcome-bienvenue-fra.aspx) même si c'est quand même employé aussi en anglais au [Canada](https://www.scc-csc.ca/court-cour/welcome-bienvenue-eng.aspx). En fait c'est encore notre [faute](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/justice), c. 1130 hahaha. Mais c'est une _toast_ qui ne nous est jamais revenue celle-là...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On appelle cette forme un "[participe passé employé comme adjectif qualificatif](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-18225.php#:%7E:text=Le%20participe%20pass%C3%A9%20employ%C3%A9%20avec,pass%C3%A9%20des%20verbes%20entre%20parenth%C3%A8ses.)".

> Les motifs qui sont rendus par la juge du procès...

Cette tournure n'est pas fausse ou grammaticalement incorrecte, elle est juste lourde.

Comment: Je vous trouve un peu dur. Des phrases comme "les raisons données ne semblaient pas valables" sont très bien.

Comment: @XouDo tout à fait- ce serait "les raisons qui sont données" qui serait lourd.

Comment: ok j'avais compris l'inverse